# Unable to download ZeroMQ dependencies with scala 2.12.6 sbt Akka

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, zeromq, akka-zeromq

I am building app with Scala 2.12.6,Akka and zeroMQ I am trying to add dependency for zeroMQ like this but facing issues while downloading dependencies for zeroMQ. I am trying to add ZeroMQ dependency like this :

```
val `akka-zeromq`     = "com.typesafe.akka"      %% "akka-zeromq"   % "2.1-M1"
```

Below section explains sbt resolvers I am using :
     resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
     resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("pqw", "maven"),
     version := "0.0.1",
     fork := true,
     parallelExecution in Test := false,
     autoCompilerPlugins := true,
     if (formatOnCompile) scalafmtOnCompile := true else scalafmtOnCompile := false

I think I did everything correct but still facing below issues while trying to run project with command sbt stage publishLocal

```
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.akka#akka-zeromq_2.12;2.1-M1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/mahendratonape/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.akka/akka-zeromq_2.12/2.1-M1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-zeromq_2.12/2.1-M1/akka-zeromq_2.12-2.1-M1.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/mahendratonape/.sbt/preloaded/com.typesafe.akka/akka-zeromq_2.12/2.1-M1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/mahendratonape/.sbt/preloaded/com/typesafe/akka/akka-zeromq_2.12/2.1-M1/akka-zeromq_2.12-2.1-M1.pom
[warn] ==== bintray-sbt-plugins: tried
[warn]   https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.akka/akka-zeromq_2.12/2.1-M1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== bintray-twtmt-maven: tried
[warn]   https://dl.bintray.com/twtmt/maven/com/typesafe/akka/akka-zeromq_2.12/2.1-M1/akka-zeromq_2.12-2.1-M1.pom
[warn] ==== mavenRepo: tried
[warn]   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.zeromq/zeromq-scala-binding/com.typesafe.akka/akka-zeromq_2.12/2.1-M1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-zeromq_2.12;2.1-M1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.typesafe.akka:akka-zeromq_2.12:2.1-M1 (/home/mahendratonape/abc4.0/acs/build.sbt#L8)
[warn]        +- org.tmt:abc-asd_2.12:0.0.1
```

Please let me know if you can provide any help for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-zeromq, version `M-1` is not released on **maven central**, but exists on **typesafe repo**.

I tried with this minimal example:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe maven releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-zeromq
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-zeromq" % "2.1-M1"
```

Reload sbt and update. Maybe try newer dependency version.

Comment: as u suggested I added typesafe repo but still I am getting issues like this :  module not found: com.typesafe.akka#akka-zeromq_2.12;2.1-M1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/akka/akka-zeromq_2.12/2.1-M1/akka-zeromq_2.12-2.1-M1.pom
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-zeromq_2.12;2.1-M1: not found
My sbt build program is trying to find it out with akka-zeromq_2.12;2.1-M1 and i think its not present on typesafe repo

Comment: may be SBT build is appending _2.12 at the end of artifact akka-zeromq because scala version i am using is 2.12.6

Comment: Yes, when you add `%%` than it appends project's scala version. Also, sorry for wrong resolver. I updated the answer.

Comment: This solved issue but i am landed in another issue now facing cross-version conflicts:Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Wrote /home/mahendratonape/csw4.0/mcs/mcs-deploy/target/scala-2.12/mcs-deploy_2.12-0.0.1.pom
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/mahendratonape/csw4.0/mcs/"), "mcs-hcd"):
[error]    com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor _2.12, <none>
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor